# How to solve this exponential limit?

Tags: limits

Does the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}x^{\cos x}$$ exist? How this limit is different from $$\lim_{x \to 0}|x|^{[\cos x]}$$, where $[x]$ means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: What does $[\phantom v]$ mean in $[\cos x]$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $[    ]$ means the greatest integer function

Answer (score 2):

In the first limit $x^{\cos x}$ is not defined if $x$ is negative. In the second limit, $|x|^{\lfloor \cos x \rfloor}$ is always defined. When $|x|$ is very small but not zero, $\lfloor \cos x \rfloor =0$. So now you can figure out both limits.